# Does MongoDB support Upsert to an Array Field

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structured as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : 1000001,
    "ListMembers" : [
            {
                    "MemberID" : 1000,
                    "Notes" : "Test Notes for 1000"
            },
            {
                    "MemberID" : 1001,
                    "Notes" : "Test Notes for 1002"
            }
    ]
```

}

The application generates a unique Id.
I need to achieve following:

1. If the document doesn't exist then Insert a new document with Array
   Field.
2. If the document exits in the collection and Member record
   exists in the array then Update the Member Notes
3. If the document exits in the collection and Member record doesn't
   exist in the array then Insert Member Record in the array.

Here #1 and #2 work fine but the {upsert:true} option doesn't work for #3 above; if the document exists but the Member Record doesn't exist, it tries to Insert a new document with the same Id which obviously gives me a Duplicate key error. Does MongoDB support UPSERT operation in this scenario OR do I need to check the existence of the document and then do INSERT for #1 and ($pull and $push) to achieve #2 and #3 on the array field.

Comment: I ran into this problem today, and found that doing $pull and then $push works for all three conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this isn't supported as the `$` [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#_S_) doesn't support upserting:

> Do not use the positional operator $ with upsert operations because, inserts will use the $ as a field name in the inserted document.

The positional operator is required to update the notes for the member record but wont work for an upsert.

The logic I would recommend is to do an update query to cover #2 and #3 - I'd make sure the [writeconcern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-write-concern) is 1 - so it returns the number of documents updated.  If it returns none do an insert to $push the item onto the `ListMembers` - this covers #1*

*There is a potential race condition here - for extra points you should ensure when you try and do the `$push` it checks that it *doesn't match* the `ListMembers` aspect and set the writeconcern.  If the `$push` operation returns 0 - that means the document was updated inbetween the first operation and this one, so you can now proceed back with the `$update` as theres is now a match and it will update it.

Comment: the race condition issue can't be resolved like this because $push creates a duplicate instead of returning 0. I could have used $addToSet if the "Notes" fields wasn't there; this creates a duplicate too because it looks at all fields (i.e. MemberID and Notes)and obviously Notes created in a race condition would be different which would prevent it to treat the record created during race condition as duplicate. So even $addToSet ends up creating another record.

Comment: When doing the $push you have to make sure you aren't doing an upsert and that the query part doesn't match - that will stop the duplication.